# How to force xcode to use ARC on a specific file?

Tags: xcode, build, xmpp, automatic-ref-counting, compiler-flags

My project contains XMPPFramework which contains a file that has to be used with ARC. But my project is Non ARC and cannot be converted due to certain other libraries linked to it.

How do I force the compiler to use ARC only on a certain class ?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It is the inverse problem of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project?rq=1). The difference is that you would use `-fobjc-arc` instead of `-fno-objc-arc`.