# Mixpanel iOS SDK and ARC

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, mixpanel

I'm trying to add the Mixpanel SDK to an iOS app that uses ARC. After adding the SDK I get some compile errors related to ARC usage. **How can I integrate Mixpanel into a project that uses ARC?**

In my personal projects I always manage mempory manually. Perhaps there's some way to tell the compiler this code uses ARC while this code doesn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click on your project name in the navigator. Choose "Build Phases" from the list header in the right hand window. You should see a bar named "Compile Sources"; expand it and you should see a list of the source files in the project and a column labeled "Compiler Flags". For every file in the Mixpanel SDK, double-click in this column and add the following line:

```
-fno-objc-arc
```

This will signal the compiler to not use Automatic Reference Counting when compiling these files. If you ever need to do the reverse (compile ARC code in a non-ARC project) do the same thing but add this line instead:

```
-fobj-arc
```

I believe this may be a duplicate of [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13392521/how-to-force-xcode-to-use-arc-on-a-specific-file)